# How to install snappy on Hadoop 1.2.1

Tags: hadoop, snappy

Is snappy integrated with hadoop or it needs to be installed separately with hadoop 1.2.1.I added following properties in mapred-site.xml file for compressing my map files.

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name>  
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.map.output.compression.codec</name>  
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec</value>
</property>
```

It's giving an Error of snappy_library not loaded.I think I'll have to install it before using the codecs.Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

As per Cloudera, if you install hadoop via a tarball, then we have to install it separately, take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/electrum/1169220).

Comment: hadoop@HadoopPseudoVM:~/snappy-1.0.3$ CFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -DNDEBUG" ./configure --prefix=$(readlink -m /home/hadoop/snappy-1.0.3)
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking build system type... ./config.guess: unable to guess system type
configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one